# open different activities from map overlays

Tags: android, coding-style

I am a very little experienced android programmer.

I have a list activity and each list item opens a new activity. There is a Map in the app where it shows balloon overlays of the locations. There are, say 4 locations, when i click any of the balloon overlay i need the activity of the corresponding index.
Eg: If i click on the balloon with index = 1, i need to display the 1st item of the list in an activity.

I am currently using the code below.

```
@Override
protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item) {

    Toast.makeText(c, "onBalloonTap for overlay index " + index,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    int index1 = index;
    Intent i = new Intent(c,FestivalEvents.class);
    i.putExtra("banner", "index1");
    c.startActivity(i);

    return true;
}
```

I am catching the intent in another activity, i.e. FestivalEvents.class as below

```
Bundle eventExtra = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(eventExtra!=null){
        int position = eventExtra.getInt("banner");
        Log.i("banner", "" + position);
        switch(position){
        case 0: Toast.makeText(mContext, ""+ position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();setUpDesc(position);break;
        case 1:Toast.makeText(mContext, ""+ position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();setUpDesc(position);break;
        case 2:Toast.makeText(mContext, ""+ position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();setUpDesc(position);break;
        case 3:Toast.makeText(mContext, ""+ position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();setUpDesc(position);break;

        }

    }
```

the app crashes with a null pointer exception with this code. I hope my code is proper in receiving intents. Or may be i'm wrong in handling the recieving intent.
I am having big time solving this. Can anybody please tell me where i may have gone wrong?

**EDIT**
my logcat:

`11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sysponent.bedford/com.sysponent.bedford.FestivalEvents}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168):at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168): at com.sysponent.bedford.FestivalEvents.onCreate(FestivalEvents.java:239)
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-02 18:45:38.858: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21168):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)`

Thank you

Comment: The problem is in `onCreate()`, can I see some more code?

Answer (score 0):

```
i.putExtra("banner", "index1");
```

Shouldn't this be

```
  i.putExtra("banner", index1);
```

Comment: i tried both, the one you said does not respond, but will try once again and will update you

Comment: About the Null Ptr Exception, post the logcat output.

Comment: i was able to send index to the activity i needed through intent, now i'm getting outOfboundException. i'll add more code and logcat for review.